# How to translate unknown old coordinates from a 1934 map of Tanzania?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal-translate, tanzania

I have a old map depicting Tanzania, dated 1934, with X and Y coordinate values. I wish to translate these locations precisely into latitude and longitude (degrees, minutes, and seconds), or any international coordinate system. Any suggestion will be most welcome.

My XY coordinate values look like this:

X = 12106.7

Y = 72776.2

Those particular coordinates should be located near 3° 21' S / 35° 29' E in lat/long.

Comment: Can you include a photo of the map?

Comment: Cliff Mugnier has an article on [Tanzania](http://www.asprs.org/a/resources/grids/02-2008-tanzania.pdf) but the false easting/northing values don't look like they would match your map's.

Comment: It might help to know if the coordinates are feet, meters or kilometers.

Comment: Mugnier reports the folowing old crs's for Tanzania "the East Africa Transverse Mercator Belts G and H are where the Central Meridians are 32°30’ and 37°30’, same False Origins as the Territorial Belts, and the South African Belts have Central Meridians of 35° to 41° at 2° intervals with a Scale Factor at Origin of Unity and have False Eastings of 250 km and False Northings of 500 km" however, your given lattitude 3°21' S is 372252 m south of the equator.